# How to refer to previous record without any ID - Hive HQL using HUE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I need to refer to previous record of particular column in Hive HQL.
Columns does not have any ID on which I can base my subquery.

[image]

This third column is what I need to get. How can I do this in HQL?

Answer (score 0):

"previous row" should be calculated based on some columns. If you have such columns, then you can use `LAG()` function.

The order of rows is determined by `order by` in the `over` clause. If you have no ID, use something else, for example, Day and KPI:

```
select  Day, KPI, 
       lag(KPI) over(order by Day, KPI) as `KPI from the record before`
 from mytable t
```

Comment: Thank you! I used LAG () but I have doubles now:

Date                       KPI KPI from row before
2020-11-27 10:20:17 0 
2020-11-27 16:39:20 1 1
2020-11-27 16:39:20 1 0

Is it bacause of the same date? How can I fix his?

Comment: @milva  For example You can remove duplicates using row_number() .  I do not know how to fix because I do not know the expected result and what the initial data.